# Asterisk conference call works with Polycom phone, but how to make it work with microsip soft-phone

Tags: asterisk

We have a vanilla Asterisk box with a bunch of Polycom 550 phones.  On the phone there is a conf softbutton that when I'm on a call talking to someone, I hit the conf button, dial a third party, wait for them to answer, then hit conf button again and then all three of us are on the same call.

Now I want to have a soft phone on my pc at home without the polycom phone.  I can dial and transfer and everything works, but I can't figure out how to do this type of conference call.

I have googled, but keep finding meetme or conference room instructions.  I think *2 does the transfer, but what can I do to make old fashioned conference calls (without a conference room).

I don't have anything in my /etc/asterisk/features files regarding this to tell me the buttons to hit.

The Polycom phones seem to use only one line when I make a conference on on them.

I'd consider different softphone program if necessary.

Comment: Sorry? Do you mean you want conference... without conference? Yes, it wil be really hard to do. Polycom phone do conference in phone, via conference room, yes.

Answer (score 0):

We found in the MicroSip Settings a checkbox for "disable multiline" that is checked by default.  Unchecking this let us do 3 way conference calling.